# How to filter outbound routing using Mule ESB?

Tags: java, esb, mule

I have a instance of Mule that is configured to process xml responses from a third party provider.  Recently the provider has moved to a new revision and hence changed the xml response.  Now I need a way to identify if the response is a v1 or v2 implementation and call the appropriate endpoint on my side to process the response.

What I have currently is:

```
<service name="processResponse">
...
    <outbound>
        <pass-through-router>
            <cxf:outbound-endpoint address="..." clientClass="..." wsdlPort="..." wsdlLocation="..." operation="..."/>
        </pass-through-router>
   </outbound>
</service>
```

I would prefer to add a filter in mule to identify the revision of the 3rd party (perhaps through the xml namespace in the response), and then call the appropriate class.  I cannot find any good examples of this.

Can someone provide an example of how this could be solved?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this example](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE2USER/Proxying+Web+Services#ProxyingWebServices-RoutingMessagesBasedonSOAPActionHeaderswithTransformations), where some version transformation is demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the most straight forward means is a filtered route using an xpath filter. First define vm services for each version. Next you'll filter to them through a service with following outbound endpoint. A catch all is always a good idea.

```
<outbound>
  <filtering-router>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint ref="Version1"/>
    <expression-filter evaluator="jxpath" expression="/your/version1/xpath/descriminator"/>
  </filtering-router>
  <filtering-router>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint ref="Version2"/>
    <expression-filter evaluator="jxpath" expression="/your/version2/xpath/descriminator"/>
  </filtering-router>
  <forwarding-catch-all-strategy>
    <stdio:outbound-endpoint system="ERR"/>
  </forwarding-catch-all-strategy>
</outbound>
```